# Как загрузить видео на сервер?

Tags: php

В просторах интернета нашёл загрузку изображений на сервер, с предварительным просмотром при помощи HTML5 Drag and Drop. Всё хорошо, работает

```
// Загрузка изображений на сервер
$('#upload-button .upload').click(function() {

    // Показываем прогресс бар
    $("#loading").show();
    // переменные для работы прогресс бара
    var totalPercent = 100 / dataArray.length;
    var x = 0;

    $('#loading-content').html('Загружен '+dataArray[0].name);
    // Для каждого файла
    $.each(dataArray, function(index, file) {   
        // загружаем страницу и передаем значения, используя HTTP POST запрос 
        $.post('upload.php', dataArray[index], function(data) {

            var fileName = dataArray[index].name;
            ++x;

            // Изменение бара загрузки
            $('#loading-bar .loading-color').css({'width' : totalPercent*(x)+'%'});
            // Если загрузка закончилась
            if(totalPercent*(x) == 100) {
                // Загрузка завершена
                $('#loading-content').html('Загрузка завершена!');

                // Вызываем функцию удаления всех изображений после задержки 1 секунда
                setTimeout(restartFiles, 1000);
            // если еще продолжается загрузка   
            } else if(totalPercent*(x) < 100) {
                // Какой файл загружается
                $('#loading-content').html('Загружается '+fileName);
            }

            // Формируем в виде списка все загруженные изображения
            // data формируется в upload.php
            var dataSplit = data.split(':');
            if(dataSplit[1] == 'загружен успешно') {
                $('#uploaded-files').append('<li><a href="images/'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+fileName+'</a> загружен успешно</li>');

            } else {
                $('#uploaded-files').append('<li><a href="images/'+data+'. Имя файла: '+dataArray[index].name+'</li>');
            }

        });
    });
    // Показываем список загруженных файлов
    $('#uploaded-files').show();
    return false;
});
```

PHP сценарий загрузки

```
<?php
// Создаем подключение к серверу
$db = mysql_connect ("localhost","root",""); 
// Выбираем БД
mysql_select_db ("Hunter",$db);

// Все загруженные файлы помещаются в эту папку
$uploaddir = 'images/add_photo/';

// Вытаскиваем необходимые данные
$file = $_POST['value'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

// Получаем расширение файла
$getMime = explode('.', $name);
$mime = end($getMime);

// Выделим данные
$data = explode(',', $file);

// Декодируем данные, закодированные алгоритмом MIME base64
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$data[1]);
$decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);

// Вы можете использовать данное имя файла, или создать произвольное имя.
// Мы будем создавать произвольное имя!
$randomName = substr_replace(sha1(microtime(true)), '', 12).'.'.$mime;

// Создаем изображение на сервере
if(file_put_contents($uploaddir.$randomName, $decodedData)) {
// Записываем данные изображения в БД
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO images (date,catalog,filename) VALUES 
(NOW(),'$uploaddir','$randomName')");
echo $randomName.":загружен успешно";
}
else {
// Показать сообщение об ошибке, если что-то пойдет не так.
echo "Что-то пошло не так. Убедитесь, что файл не поврежден!";
}
?>
```

Всё отлично, сами картинки загружаются в нужную папку(которую указали), в таблицу заносится их путь. При выводе соответственно вытаскивается путь

```
<?
// Если количество записей больше нуля
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
// Записываем полученные данные в массив
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
// В цикле выводи изображения на страницу
do {
echo "<img src='admin_panel/".$myrow['catalog'].$myrow['filename']."' />";
} 
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
}
else
{
// Собщение о пустой таблице
echo "<p>Информация по запросу не может быть извлечена, в таблице нет 
записей.</p>";
exit();                                             }
?>
```

Подскажите, как сделать тоже самое , но с видео ? Никак не могу додумать :(

Comment: С чем именно возникает проблема, когда вы пытаетесь додумать?

Comment: @andreymal ну, просто перетащить загрузить видео я не могу(не смотря на функцию, если пытаемся загрузить НЕ картинку). Я так понимаю, обработчику нужно дать знать формат видео? То есть как то надо приписать загруженным файла Mp4 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217964/upload-video-files-via-php-and-save-them-in-appropriate-folder-and-have-a-databa/18219669